# Clearing out Thunderbird on Ubuntu

Tags: backup, thunderbird, email, gmail

I installed thunderbird on Ubuntu and started downloading emails via POP just to have a backup on my local machine.  I downloaded about half of all the emails and then it said no more new emails and nothing else would come through.
I un-installed and installed Thunderbird again which of course did nothing.
Then I went into the .thunderbird/abcdefg.default/Mail and deleted pop.gmail.com.  Not sure it was a very wise thing to do but it didn't help.  I don't see any emails in my Inbox anymore but when I try to "get mail" it says "no new email".  How can I just start anew and re-download the complete email store from gmail?  I'm trying to have a complete backup of my emails that is easily accessible.  Anything else I can use besides Thunderbird?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do, if I had web access to the pop mail server, is to check and see if there are any emails still on it.

It sounds like you have Thunderbird set up to delete emails after downloading them. You can check that by Clicking on Tools, then Account Settings, then on the email account you need, then on Server Settings. Now, look at the 2nd section down, and see if there is a check mark in the box that says Leave messages on server. If not, they were probably deleted after downloading.

If you did this on a Linux system, you are probably out of luck. If you did it on a windows system, you may be able to retrieve them after a complete System Restore.

Good luck!